# Groovy: Parsing file with specific extension for import to MySQL and then rename it to *.bak

Tags: mysql, file, parsing, groovy

I made a script for connecting to database and changing data in specific column for definitely number.
Now i want read a numbers from text file with specific extension, making changes for those numbers in database and then rename file with .bak extension.
help me, please. i appreciate your help in advance!

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
sql = Sql.newInstance('jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database', 'login', 'password', 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver')
int rowsAffected = sql.executeUpdate('update tablename set column = '01' where number=$NumberFromFile')
println "updated: ${rowsAffected}"
```

Comment: Is your file just lines of text with `oldNum newNum`?

Comment: file contain numerical values of the eight digits, separated by ";", like: 12345678;87654321; ... etc

Comment: Ahhhh...  you want to set them all to `newNum`?

Comment: i want to set "column = '01'" for all numbers from file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
def newValue = '01'

new File( '/path/to/data.input' ).with { file ->
  file.withReader { reader ->
    new Scanner( reader ).useDelimiter( ';' ).with { scanner ->
      while( scanner.hasNext() ) {
        sql.executeUpdate "UPDATE tablename SET column=$newValue WHERE number=${scanner.nextInt()}"
      }
    }
  }
  file.renameTo( new File( file.parent, "${file.name}.bak" ) )
}
```

Obviously, you probably want to do it in a transaction, or a batch, but this should give you the idea

Comment: Nov 19, 2012 3:42:18 PM org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.StackTraceUtils sanitize

WARNING: Sanitizing stacktrace:

java.util.InputMismatchException

Comment: @MarkTailor On which line? Is your input file all one line of code? Try replacing the `sql.executeUpdate` with `println` does it print anything? Does the file have a `;` at the very end?

Comment: problem was in file, because after ";" i had a "newline" separator, so i added useDelimiter("\r\n") and now its work for me. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

now i have a script:

```
def tmn_file = ~/.*\.tmn/
def tmc_file = ~/.*\.tmc/
def newTerm = new Properties().with { props ->
    new File(inputPath).eachFile(tmn_file) { file ->
        file.withReader    { reader ->
            load( reader )
            println "Read data from file $file:"
            something read from file...
            switch( props.ACTION ) {
                case 'NEW':
                    do something...
                    }
            switch( props.ACTION ) {
                case 'CHANGE':
                    do something...
                    }
```

this script looking in directory with path inputPath file with extension tmn_file, which can containt ACTION - NEW or CHANGE.

Script works great, but i want to make another thing:

if file have extension *.tmn (tmn_file) - start only ACTION with NEW case

if file have extension *.tmc (tmc_file) - start only ACTION with CHANGE case

How i can realize decision?